# pyspark dataframe drop duplicate values with older time stamp

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that has starttime and stoptime columns with additional columns whose values get updated

```
|startime  |stoptime  |hour  |minute  |sec  |sip          |dip            |sport|dport|proto|pkt |byt |
|1504766585|1504801216|16    |20      |16   |192.168.0.11 |23.204.108.58  |51249|80   |6    |0   |0   |
|1504766585|1504801216|16    |20      |16   |192.168.0.11 |23.204.108.58  |51249|80   |6    |0   |0   |
|1504781751|1504801216|16    |20      |16   |192.168.0.11 |23.72.38.96    |51252|80   |6    |0   |0   |
|1504781751|1504801216|16    |20      |16   |192.168.0.11 |23.72.38.96    |51252|80   |6    |0   |0   |
|1504766585|1504801336|16    |22      |16   |192.168.0.11 |23.204.108.58  |51249|80   |6    |0   |0   |
|1504766585|1504801336|16    |22      |16   |192.168.0.11 |23.204.108.58  |51249|80   |6    |0   |0   |
|1504781751|1504801336|16    |22      |16   |192.168.0.11 |23.72.38.96    |51252|80   |6    |0   |0   |
|1504781751|1504801336|16    |22      |16   |192.168.0.11 |23.72.38.96    |51252|80   |6    |0   |0   |
```

In this example I want to select all rows with latest stoptime, all the other column values are duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm gessing you want to keep the latest record for every `sport`. You should use a window function to determine the latest record for each partition:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("sport").orderBy(psf.desc("stoptime"))

df.withColumn("rn", psf.row_number().over(w)).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")

    +----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
    |  startime|  stoptime|hour|min|sec|         sip|          dip|sport|dport|proto|pkt|byt|
    +----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
    |1504781751|1504801336|  16| 22| 16|192.168.0.11|  23.72.38.96|51252|   80|    6|  0|  0|
    |1504766585|1504801336|  16| 22| 16|192.168.0.11|23.204.108.58|51249|   80|    6|  0|  0|
    +----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
```

You'll end up with as many records as there are distinct partitions for `sport`.

If you want the latest `stoptime` for the whole table without partitioning you can remove the `partitionBy` and use `dense_rank` instead (same values will have the same rank):

```py
w = Window.orderBy(psf.desc("stoptime"))

df.withColumn("rn", psf.dense_rank().over(w)).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn").show()

    +----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
    |  startime|  stoptime|hour|min|sec|         sip|          dip|sport|dport|proto|pkt|byt|
    +----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
    |1504766585|1504801336|  16| 22| 16|192.168.0.11|23.204.108.58|51249|   80|    6|  0|  0|
    |1504766585|1504801336|  16| 22| 16|192.168.0.11|23.204.108.58|51249|   80|    6|  0|  0|
    |1504781751|1504801336|  16| 22| 16|192.168.0.11|  23.72.38.96|51252|   80|    6|  0|  0|
    |1504781751|1504801336|  16| 22| 16|192.168.0.11|  23.72.38.96|51252|   80|    6|  0|  0|
    +----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: I wanted rows with same "startime, hour, min, sec, sip, dip, sport, dport, proto" but with the latest 'stoptime'. That in turn will give me the max byt and pkt

Comment: If you need the maximum `stoptime` value for each distinct `startime, hour, min, sec, sip, dip, sport, dport, proto`. you just have to but all of these columns in the `partitionBy`

Comment: Does this look right?
`import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("startime","hour","sip","dip","sport","dport","proto").orderBy(psf.desc("stoptime"))

df = dataframe.withColumn("rn", psf.row_number().over(w)).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")
df.show()`

Comment: It does look right, do check out the output to see if it matches your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = sc.parallelize([(1504766585,1504801216,16,20,16,'192.168.0.11','23.204.108.58',51249,80,6,0,0),
                     (1504766585,1504801216,16,20,16,'192.168.0.11','23.204.108.58',51249,80,6,0,0),
                     (1504781751,1504801216,16,20,16,'192.168.0.11','23.72.38.96',  51252,80,6,0,0),
                     (1504781751,1504801216,16,20,16,'192.168.0.11','23.72.38.96',  51252,80,6,0,0),
                     (1504766585,1504801336,16,22,16,'192.168.0.11','23.204.108.58',51249,80,6,0,0),
                     (1504766585,1504801336,16,22,16,'192.168.0.11','23.204.108.58',51249,80,6,0,0),
                     (1504781751,1504801336,16,22,16,'192.168.0.11','23.72.38.96',  51252,80,6,0,0),
                     (1504781751,1504801336,16,22,16,'192.168.0.11','23.72.38.96',  51252,80,6,0,0)]).\
    toDF(["startime","stoptime","hour","min","sec","sip","dip","sport","dport","proto","pkt","byt"])

df1 = df.where(col("stoptime") == df.select("stoptime").rdd.max()[0]).distinct()
df1.show()
```

Output is

```python
+----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
|  startime|  stoptime|hour|min|sec|         sip|          dip|sport|dport|proto|pkt|byt|
+----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
|1504766585|1504801336|  16| 22| 16|192.168.0.11|23.204.108.58|51249|   80|    6|  0|  0|
|1504781751|1504801336|  16| 22| 16|192.168.0.11|  23.72.38.96|51252|   80|    6|  0|  0|
+----------+----------+----+---+---+------------+-------------+-----+-----+-----+---+---+
```

Comment: Just added (Python) code highlighting - look for <!-- language-all: lang-python --> in the beginning of your code...

Comment: @user2825083 you should mark it as the correct answer if it answered your query as it'll help others in case they face similar issue in future. Thanks!

Comment: collecting pyspark values into python objects can have unexpected results for `float` since they are not approximated the same way. I would not recommend doing it.

Comment: @Marie care to explain more if you don't mind? I couldn't find any non-spark objects used in here?

Comment: `df.select("stoptime").rdd.max()[0]` is a python `int`

Comment: You're also converting it to rdd for aggregation which is less efficient than the dataframe aggregation

Comment: @Marie I think we should always talk sensible and be ready to defend any theoretical assumption before posting something (e.g. first you talk about float then int then rdd vs df). Shouldn't we concentrate on helping community members rather than this sort of dialogue exchanges? (BTW - this [benchmark testing](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/42027/rdd-vs-dataframe-vs-sparksql.html) might interest you). Pls don't intimidate OP with so many comments. Be a sport!!!

Comment: oh no no, I guess messages can be misleading... It wasn't my intention to come off as demeaning, I was also just trying to help. I spent time trying to find a reproducible example for `float`, it's a problem I had to solve for a colleague of mine and I couldn't reproduce it. I also ran into this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46122846/pyspark-inconsistency-in-converting-timestamp-to-integer-in-dataframe a couple of days ago so I knew other people ran into this conversion problem. I was just advising not to go back and forth between python and spark if it can be avoided. Sorry again

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Will this also work?
`from pyspark.sql.functions import col, max as max_

dataframe.groupBy(dataframe.trhour, dataframe.trminute, dataframe.trsec, dataframe.starttime, dataframe.sip, dataframe.dip, dataframe.sport, dataframe.dport, dataframe.proto, dataframe.ipkt, dataframe.ibyt).agg(max_('stoptime'))`

Comment: @user2825083 This should work but wouldn't it give maximum value rows in 'each' group?

Comment: @Prem This solution will give only rows with max stoptime.

Comment: But in your original post you sounded differently. It looks like a case of wrong requirement gathering :) - I thought that you only wanted to have the rows having latest 'stoptime' (irrespective of group!!!). I would suggest to update the question properly with expected output so that other users don't get confused while looking for an answer to their problem. Thanks!