# PySpark: inconsistency in converting timestamp to integer in dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, dataframe, pyspark, bigdata

I have a dataframe with a rough structure like the following:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| timestamp               | adj_timestamp           | values |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 2017-05-31 15:30:48.000 | 2017-05-31 11:30:00.000 | 0      |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 2017-05-31 15:31:45.000 | 2017-05-31 11:30:00.000 | 0      |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| 2017-05-31 15:32:49.000 | 2017-05-31 11:30:00.000 | 0      |
...
```

I am trying to apply a conversion function to the two time columns to turn them into their integer representation using the `time` package. My user defined function and how it is applied to the dataframe above:

```
def timeConverter(timestamp):
    time_tuple = time.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000")
    timevalue = time.mktime(time_tuple)
    return timevalue

def convertDateColumn(Data):
    timeUDF = udf(timeConverter,FloatType())
    finalData = Data.withColumn('adj_timestamp', timeUDF('adj_timestamp'))

    return finalData
```

For example, the first entry in the `adj_timestamp` column becomes:
`1496244608`

Converting this back via `datetime.fromtimestamp` results in: `2017-05-31 15:30:08`

Which is not the same value that I started with... Curious as to what is going on!

EDIT: Since I have far more rows than the 3 shown, is it possible that the data is being processed asynchronously and therefore the resulting dataframe is not in the same order as it was fed in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `udf`, I'm not quite sure yet why it's not working. It might be float manipulation problem when converting Python function to UDF. See how using interger output works below. Alternatively, you can resolve using a Spark function called `unix_timestamp` that allows you convert timestamp. I give an example below. Hope it helps a bit.

Here I create Spark dataframe from examples that you show,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['2017-05-31 15:30:48.000', '2017-05-31 11:30:00.000', 0], 
    ['2017-05-31 15:31:45.000', '2017-05-31 11:30:00.000', 0],
    ['2017-05-31 15:32:49.000', '2017-05-31 11:30:00.000', 0]], 
    columns=['timestamp', 'adj_timestamp', 'values'])
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

### Solve by using Spark function

Apply `fn.unix_timestamp` to the column `timestamp`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fn
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df.select(fn.unix_timestamp(fn.col('timestamp'), format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000').alias('unix_timestamp')).show()
```

For the first column, the output looks like this

```
+--------------+
|unix_timestamp|
+--------------+
|    1496259048|
|    1496259105|
|    1496259169|
+--------------+
```

You can put this back to timestamp using `datetime` library:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1496259048) # output as datetime(2017, 5, 31, 15, 30, 48)
```

### Solve by converting to interger instead of float

```
import datetime
import time

def timeConverter(timestamp):
    time_tuple = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000").timetuple()
    timevalue = int(time.mktime(time_tuple)) # convert to int here
    return timevalue

time_udf = fn.udf(timeConverter, IntegerType()) # output interger

df.select(time_udf(fn.col('timestamp')))
```

Here, we will get the same timestamp `[1496259048, 1496259105, 1496259169]` as using `unix_timestamp`.

Comment: Awesome! This fixed up many more issues that I had (with doubling of results, for example). Oddly enough, I find that all of my time values are offset by 4 hours.. Not sure why but if you have any insight that would be great!

Comment: Seems like we have to check the Spark issue for this. They probably know what's going on when converting this float value.