# Pyspark dataframe remove duplicate in AWS Glue Script

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have a script in AWS Glue ETL Job, where it reads a S3 bucket with a lot of parquet files, do a sort by key1, key2 and a timestamp field. After that the script delete the duplicates and save a single parquet file in other S3 Bucket.

Look the data I have before the Job runs:

| key1 | key2 | uploadTimestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0005541779 | 10 | 2021-12-29 14:54:08.753 |
| 0005541779 | 10 | 2021-12-29 15:06:05.968 |

The code that do the sort and eliminate duplicates:

```
#############################################################

tempDF = S3bucket_node1.toDF() #from Dynamic Frame to Data Frame

sortedDF = tempDF.orderBy(f.col("uploadTimestamp").desc(),"key1","key2").dropDuplicates(["key1","key2"]) #sort and remove duplicates


dynamicFrame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(sortedDF, glueContext, 'salesOrder') #back to Dynamic Frame

#############################################################
```

Get a look on this image after an order by:
[image]

My problem:
In the output file, some data got the last timestamp, some data got the first.. I can't understand why it doesnt work for all data.

Thanks.

Comment: There might be whitespaces at the end of column "key1" or column "key2" values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It worked with the following code:

```
tempDF = S3bucket_node1.toDF()

w = Window.partitionBy("key1","key2").orderBy(f.desc("uploadTimestamp"))
df = tempDF.withColumn("rn", f.row_number().over(w)).filter("rn = 1").drop("rn")

dynamicFrame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, 'dynamicFrame')
```

The tip to solve that, was found here:
[pyspark dataframe drop duplicate values with older time stamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102339/pyspark-dataframe-drop-duplicate-values-with-older-time-stamp)